# How can I read through multiple layers of a tilemap to determine what tiles exist at a clicked on position in a script for unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whats going on is, I want to detect what the tile I'm clicking on is, but I'm unsure of how I can do that if my tilemap consists of multiple layers. For example, with the way my script is currently set up, the ground level 'island' can be passed into the script as the 'map' variable, but then I wont be able to see if I am clicking on the house, which is in a separate layer. I'm new to Unity so I apologize if I'm explaining it badly, but basically I need a way to look through multiple layers of the tilemap to see what is being clicked on. In the future I would want to implement some sort of system in which a tile could have some sort of modifier sprite on top of it in a higher layer, so I would want to see the tiles in both layers, another reason I'm wondering if there's a way to cycle through those tiles.

[image: Here is my scene/tilemap and hierarchy so you can see all the layers in the tilemap]

[image: And here is the script I was/am using to click on a tile and get what type of tile it is, but it currently only can accept one layer of the map as an input and see what tile exists at the specifies coordinate on that layer.]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by looping through layers.

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Tilemap> mapLayers;

    [SerializeField] private List<TileData> tileDatas;

    private Dictionary<TileBase, TileData> dataFromTiles;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            Dictionary<TileBase, int> foundTiles = new Dictionary<TileBase, int>();
            TileBase clickedTile = null;
            Vector3Int gridPosition = Vector3Int.zero;
            foreach (var layer in mapLayers)
            {
                gridPosition = layer.WorldToCell(mousePosition);
                
                // Get access to TileMap's component, which stores sorting layer
                TilemapRenderer renderer = layer.GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>();

                clickedTile = layer.GetTile(gridPosition);
                
                if (clickedTile != null)
                {
                    // Collect all tiles, which are in the current clicked cell
                    foundTiles.Add(clickedTile, renderer.sortingOrder);
                }                
            }

            if (foundTiles.Count > 0)
            {
                // Find the tile with highest sorting order
                clickedTile = foundTiles.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? x : y).Key;
                print("Position " + gridPosition + ", tile " + clickedTile);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I do not know is there an Unity solution for it, but this works for me.

P.S. Please, use code blocks for code instead of screenshots.